# angular reload an existing promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a service that returns a promise to a controller:

```
// .... in the service
this.RefreshData = function() {
    this.data = $q.all( {images: ...., tags: ....}); 
}
RefreshData ();

// .... in the controller
function() OnImages() {.....};
ImageSrv.data.then(OnImages());
```

But now something happened somewhere else and I want to refresh my controller as well. Lets say some directive calls my Service. and refreshes it

```
ImageSrv.RefreshData();
```

My promise has changed, OnImages won't fire now.
Is the correct way to handle this with a promise + an event? I really wish I could just do something like

```
ImageSrv.data.refresh()
```

which will change the promise to "not resolved" and try to resolve it again.

Comment: `RefreshData()` shouldn't *store* the promise in `.data` where it is consumed, but rather *`return`* it! You'd re-attach the handler after each call.

Comment: @Bergi I'm well aware that whoever called the RefreshData, can easily re attach his handler. I'm asking about all the poor controllers and services who already attached to the previous instance of the promise...

Answer (score 0):

That's not how promises work. There is no mechanism that makes promises aware that they've changed. Promises only resolve (or reject) once, and then they are done. There is nothing that tells your controller that something has changed, and that `OnImages` needs to run again.

One solution might be to trigger some event that your controller will listen to, and then re-run `OnImages`.